# Convert TimeIndex of dataframe to DateTimeIndex in place

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index, datetimeindex

Coming from a `MultiIndex`:

[image: multiindex_time_index]

I can select the `TimeIndex` using `get_level_values`

```
hist_vol_to_display.index.get_level_values('ts_timeonly')
```

[image: pandas dataframe timeindex to be converted to DateTimeIndex]

So all of the rows have happend on a specific date (e.g. 2019-09-16).

**What is an efficient way to replace the `TimeIndex` with a `DateTimeIndex`?**

Can I replace the Index `inplace` or do I need to work around this using a new column? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`MultiIndex.set_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html):

```
x  = pd.to_datetime('2019-09-16 ' + hist_vol_to_display.index.levels[1].astype(str))
hist_vol_to_display.index = hist_vol_to_display.index.set_levels(x, level=1)
```